# Account Suspended in webassesor during salesforce exam

Tags: certification

I have scheduled my App builder exam on 29th November 7:45 AM IST, while writing my exam it got stuck in middle and could not go forward. I requested help from the support members and he rescheduled my exam to 6:30 PM IST. 
When i launched exam at 6:30 PM IST i was able to answer only one question and again it stuck. Later i took help from kryterion member and launced exam again and this time it dint take me to the questions also. i faced camera issues and some times photo enrollment was not able to retrieve and the exam was suspended.
I have raised case to sales force. Any thing else i could do to reschedule my exam asap.

Comment: On the off chance you come back can you please accept the answer below a the correct one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Salesforce exam policy Kryterion support can schedule exam exam for the same day only so if they are not able to schedule now you need to open a case from certification.salesforce.com. Salesforce support team will issue a new coupon code which you can use to re schedule your exam. The whole process will take 3-4 days

Comment: I submitted a case over 3 months ago to reset my biometrics as I got a new camera. I am still waiting for a response. Good luck.

Comment: I've found with the certification support team, they don't seem to have the "must close cases" drive that customer support has. So, I just send a follow up email every single day until they respond. It usually takes about a week of daily emails, but they cave.

Comment: is there any other channels to contact sales force  to have this re-scheduled soon.....

Comment: Sadly, I don't see any other way. As we all said already you can only drop an email at regular interval

Comment: To whom i need to send mail, could you provide any mail address

Comment: Thank you! @Himanshu, Christian Carter, Eric. Issue is resloved.

Comment: great.. Best of luck for your exam :)